# What will happen if server implement spdy/3 while browser only support spdy/2?

Tags: spdy

What will happen if I add support for spdy/3 on my server, while my users only have spdy/2 in their browsers?
Will the protocol degrade gracefully to spdy/2 or it will only use plain https?

Comment: I can no longer vote to re-open, but this is an important question for those implementing the SPDY protocol. I do not think it is off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

Servers that supports SPDY such as [Jetty](http://webtide.intalio.com/2012/03/spdy-support-in-jetty/) advertise the protocols that they are able to support via [NPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_Protocol_Negotiation), and usually there always is "http/1.1" among them.

If your server advertises "spdy/3","http/1.1", and the browser only supports "spdy/2", then the browser (being a browser means it supports HTTP by default) will fallback to "http/1.1" over TLS.

There is no degradation to spdy/2 if the server does not support it (spdy/2 and spdy/3 are binary incompatible).
If a protocol negotiation is not possible, the connection is closed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helps. Is it possible for a server to support more than one version of spdy? let's say it supports both spdy/2 and spdy/3 at the same time.

Comment: Sure, it would just advertise both spdy/2 and spdy/3 via NPN, and then use whichever version the client requests.